# Consecutive pressing mapped function keys emits unwanted "^[[I" in input buffer in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: key-bindings, linux-ubuntu

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 (ubuntu-22.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso)

Vim: vim-gtk3 (8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.7 amd64)

vimrc:

```
nnoremap <F7> : ! g++ % -o %< <CR>
nnoremap <F8> : ! time ./%< <CR>
```

*Immediately* at the "Press Enter or type command to continue" prompt (for example, after pressing F7 for compiling a single file c++ program), press F8 will emit `^[[I` in the input buffer. I could use backspace to delete them and they will be caught by that program in standard input if I don't do so.

```bash
Press ENTER or type command to continue
^[[I
```

I find this issue on a physical machine, and I could reproduce this problem by reinstalling a brand new virtual box environment. However, if I remembered it correctly, there is no such problem before Ubuntu 18.04 (or in older vim-gnome?)

I read some tutorials online, there are some posts about arrow keys (`^[[A` to `^[[D`) that seem to be relative, but I could not find anything helpful about `^[[I`.

Here are some observations about this issue:

1. Consecutive F7 presses also produce `^[[I`.
2. Replace the F8 command `nnoremap <F8> : ! time <CR>`, `^[[I` disappeared *sometimes*: press F8 consecutively, `^[[I` still appears if the command lag for some reason. It seems that some key-like input sent to terminal after a short delay. It may be something related to terminal, but still I have no idea about it.

```bash
real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s

Press ENTER or type command to continue

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
^[[I
Press ENTER or type command to continue

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s

Press ENTER or type command to continue

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

3. I tried to use hacks to avoid this problem, for example, `nnoremap <F8> : ! echo "" && time ./%< <CR>` which hopes the `^[[I` redirected to the first echo, but it doesn't work.
4. Something like `nnoremap <F8> : ! <CR> : ! time ./%< <CR>` makes things even worse: there will be `^[[I^[[I` in the terminal.
5. If I removed the `<CR>` (`nnoremap <F8> : ! time ./%<`) and press enter manually, it works fine. Maybe there's something related to `<CR>`?

Comment: Weclome to vi SE. Please do not use images for text like console output etc.

Comment: Sure, I've replaced them. Thank you!